# how do you make a background in allegro with c++?

Tags: c++, background, allegro

i'm fairly new at programming with allegro, and i wanna change the background color of my programs from something more pleasant than black *haha* :) can some one help please?

and just for a reference of what im doing

```
#include <allegro.h>

BITMAP* buffer;
BITMAP* bmp;
int cursor_x = 20;
int cursor_y = 20;

int getMouseInfo(){
     if(mouse_b & 1){
                  cursor_x = mouse_x;
                  cursor_y = mouse_y;
      return 1;
     }
  return 0;
}
void updateScreen(){

     show_mouse(NULL);
     circlefill ( buffer, cursor_x, cursor_y, 60, makecol( 0, 255 , 0));
     draw_sprite( screen, buffer, 0, 0);  
}
int main(){

    allegro_init();
    install_mouse();
    install_keyboard();
    set_color_depth(16);
    set_gfx_mode( GFX_AUTODETECT, 640, 480, 0, 0);
    rectfill (  

    buffer = create_bitmap( 640, 480);     


    show_mouse(screen);        

    while( !key[KEY_ESC])
 {
  int switcher=1;
  while(getMouseInfo()) 
  { 
   updateScreen();
   if(getMouseInfo()==0) switcher=0;
  }
  if(switcher==0) show_mouse(screen);

    }

 return 0; 
}
END_OF_MAIN();
```

Comment: In Allegro 4, you'll typically be working with an offscreen bitmap buffer that you've created. Ultimately you'll find out that every frame you'll need to clear it and redraw the frame... so there's no extra work in clearing it to something other than black.

Answer (score 2):

To create backgroud bitmap try this:

```
/* Make a bitmap in RAM. */
  BITMAP *bmp = create_bitmap(SCR_X, SCR_Y);
```

then try this to clear bmp to some different color:

> ```
>   /* Clear the screen to red. */
>   clear_to_color(bmp, makecol(255, 0, 0));
> ```

or this to load bitmap from file:

```
bmp = load_bitmap("image.pcx", palette);
```

Then you just need to blit this bitmap with your screen - like this:

```
  /* Blit bmp on the screen. */
  blit(bmp, screen, 0, 0, 0, 0, bmp->w, bmp->h);
```

Comment: `clear_bitmap(bmp)` is a synonymous call to `clear_to_color(bmp, makecol(0, 0, 0))`. Calling `clear_to_color(...)` right after `clear_bmp(...)` is a waste. Just call `clear_to_color(...)`. Also, just call `BITMAP* bmp = load_bitmap("image.pcx", palette)`, you don't need to "Make a bitmap in RAM" first.

Answer (score 0):

Draw a screen-sized rectangle that is the color you want the background to be. Or just use `clear_bitmap` to clear the screen.

Comment: yeah i was hoping that i wouldnt have to draw a rectangle

Answer (score -3):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<" In the world were gamers play MINECRAFT, where they creating everithing they   can emagine ...\n";
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```